# Custom Properties Error for Webpart SP 2007

Tags: web-part

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
```

I am using the above header files

```
public class ApplicationForm : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
    {
        // WebPart Parameter for getting the Connection string
        [
        WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Connection String"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)

        ]
    }
```

It throws an error for custom attribute:

```
Error   1   Attribute 'WebBrowsable' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.
```

Comment: Is that the complete snippet? As mentioned in the error the attributes should be on a Property or an Indexer. The snippet given in the question does not have anything after the attributes

Comment: You're welcome. You could post it and mark that as the answer

Comment: See [my question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18935/easy-way-to-add-a-custom-web-part-property-to-a-web-part) for a complete example (and an easy way to add web part properties!).