# Own Webpart properties for each webpart

Tags: web-part

I have created my first Webpart with own properties:

```
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class BildMitHyperlink : WebPart
{
    [WebBrowsable(true), Category("MY"), DefaultValue(""), WebDisplayName("Hyperlink"), WebDescription("Der Hyperlink der gestartet werden soll, sobald auf das Bild geklickt wird.")]
    public string Hyperlink
    {
        get { return _hyperlink; }
        set { _hyperlink = value; }
    }
    public static string _hyperlink;



        protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = (BildMitHyperlink)Parent;

        if (parent.NeuesFenster)
            Response.Redirect(parent.Hyperlink, "_blank", null);
        else
            Response.Redirect(parent.Hyperlink);
    }
```

My Problem is: 
When i create more then one WebPart on the same Page, the properties are shared on each WebPart! So if i change a propertie of one of the webparts - its change all my webparts?!

How can i make own properties for each Webpart?

Thanks 4 Answer!

Comment: Ahh! Thats it! Thanks 4 your fast answer and help!

Comment: No prob, if it works for you, feel free to mark it as 'Answered'

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that the **_hyperlink** variable should not be static. All the web parts of this type share the same C# class, so setting _hyperlink would reset that variable for *all* those web parts.

It probably shouldn't be public, either, as you've provided a property to access it.

Comment: Example of a properly implemented web part property: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18935/easy-way-to-add-a-custom-web-part-property-to-a-web-part